# Centering page content divs in centered webpages

Tags: css, xhtml

Keeping in mind that this question has probably been asked in many forms.  I just don't seem to be getting it.  I want to center masthead, top nav, page content, and footer divs in a centered web page.  I'm new to this and it is kicking my you know what. Exactly what do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all of your inner divs in another div. Usually called/classed container or wrapper.

Then set a width on your container/wrapper and "zero" the margin.

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- all of your site in here -->
</div>

.container {
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: One important addition, to make it work in IE you have to use a proper doctype. Make sure that your HTML code has following line at the very top: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
    .wrapper{
                margin:0 auto;
                width:960px;
}
```

This will set a margin of 0 to both the top & bottom of the div and auto to the left and right.